# How to rotate while preserving the size in Java?

Tags: java, rotation, affinetransform

I have been trying to no avail. I want a 128x128 image be rotated using AffineTransform but whenever I rotate it to a specific degree, I get a 130x133 or 131x129 image. I want to preserve its 128x128. How do I do this in Java using AffineTransform? Or can this be done in any other methods? Thank you!

```
public BufferedImage generate() {
    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
    tx.rotate(Math.toRadians(0.1));
    AffineTransformOp operation = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC);
    BufferedImage t = operation.createCompatibleDestImage(img, img.getColorModel());
    return operation.filter(img, t);
}
```

Comment: Surely you can crop it post-rotation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CropImageFilter` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/CropImageFilter.html) to crop your image after rotation.